# SQL Server stored procedure output parameter is not returning correct output after insert statement using PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, php-7.1

SQL Server stored procedure is not returning correct output while using it with PHP.

My development environment:

- PHP 7.1
- SQL Server 2017 Express Edition
- Ubuntu 16.04

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest]
    @TestID BIGINT,
    @QueryStatus BIGINT = 0 OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @QueryStatus = 0;

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF(@TestID = 1)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.tblErrorLog (ErrorMessage) 
            VALUES('Test Data');

            SET @QueryStatus = 1;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
            SET @QueryStatus = -1;
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        SET @QueryStatus = -999;

        INSERT INTO dbo.tblErrorLog (ErrorMessage) 
        VALUES(ERROR_MESSAGE());
    END CATCH
END
```

And using following PHP code for executing this stored procedure:

```
$SQL = "{call spTest (@TestID=?,?)}";
//$SQLParam=array($Email,$Referer);
$QueryResult=-997;
$TestID=1;

$SQLParam = array(
    array($TestID,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$QueryResult, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT,SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_INT)
);
$SQLResult = $SQLServer_DB_Manager->executeQuery($SQL,$SQLParam);


echo "Query Result for Test ID 1: ".$QueryResult." <br/>";

$QueryResult=-997;
$TestID=0;

$SQLParam = array(
    array($TestID,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$QueryResult, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT,SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT,SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_INT)
);
$SQLResult = $SQLServer_DB_Manager->executeQuery($SQL,$SQLParam);


echo "Query Result for Test ID 0: ".$QueryResult." <br/>";
```

Finally, Result is

- Query Result for Test ID 1: -997
- Query Result for Test ID 0: -1

But as per the stored procedure, the expected out for first execution must be 1. If I am going to comment out the `Insert` statement in the stored procedure, I will get the expected result. Is there anyone who can help me to find out what is wrong?

Comment: If I run the query in SSMS test id = 1 I get `1`. Check so that you are really sending a 1 as the test id by running the SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Yes, I am getting one in SSMS. SSMS is not an issue. PHP is the issue.

Comment: Exactly... check what php is sending in using the profiler.

Comment: Profiler Result declare @ p2 int
set @ p2=NULL
exec spTest 1,@ p2 output
select @ p2 ignore white space between @ and the variable name.

Comment: F__k, What the hell I am doing. Sry for the trouble  SET NOCOUNT ON ressolved my issue. Can you please delete this question. I think it will not help others. Because as per the best practive we must need to use it.